# Can't seem to get my string to iterate in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a string that will have multiple values, `person_ids` and how many vacation days they have. I want to use this data in my view.

Here is my MyGroupAcc model:

```
class MyGroupAcc < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :entry

def self.all_people
  where(person_id: User.all.pluck(:person_id))
end

def self.active_people
  all_people.where(is_active: 'Y')
end

def self.active_vacation_data
  active_people.select(:person_id, :accum_accrued, :taken)
end

def total_v_hours
  accum_accrued.to_d - taken.to_d
end

def total_v_days
   total_v_hours / 8
end
```

Here is my entry controller where my view action will be:

```
def my_group
  peoples_vacation_information = MyGroupAcc.active_vacation_data.all
  peoples_vacation_information.map do |person|
    @p = "person #{person.person_id} has #{person.total_v_days} vacation days"
  end
  render :my_group
end
```

And here is `my_group` view in Haml:

```
%table.table.table-bordered.trace-table
  %thead
    %tr.trace-table
      %th.ts.jp{:style => 'border: solid black;'} Person ID
      %th.ts.jp{:style => 'border: solid black;'} Total Vacation Days

      %tr.trace-table
      -@p.each do |r|
        %tr.trace-table
          %td.trace-table{:style => 'border: solid black;'}= r
```

In my view I get this error:

```
udefined method `each' for "person 22076 has 3.0 vacation days":String
```

but in my console it get this when running this code

```
peoples_vacation_information = MyGroupAcc.active_vacation_data.all
peoples_vacation_information.map do |person|
    @p = "person #{person.person_id} has #{person.total_v_days} vacation days"
end
```

Which spits out this, which is what I would like to see in my view:

```
["person 16016 has 7.0 vacation days", "person 16256 has 0.0 vacation days", "person 16256 has 18.5 vacation days", "person 17258 has 0.0 vacation days", "person 17258 has 5.0 vacation days", "person 17371 has 0.0 vacation days", "person 17371 has 20.0 vacation days", "person 19551 has 0.0 vacation days", "person 19551 has 26.5 vacation days", "person 20850 has 0.5 vacation days", "person 20850 has 14.0 vacation days", "person 21714 has 0.5 vacation days", "person 21714 has 1.0 vacation days", "person 22076 has 0.0 vacation days", "person 22076 has 3.0 vacation days"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@p` is here just a simple string, not an array or a collection.

you can solve this with this

```
@p=peoples_vacation_information.map do |person|
  "person #{person.person_id} has #{person.total_v_days} vacation days"
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much wow can't believe I didn't catch that must need more coffee! @rob

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
def my_group
   @peoples_vacation_information = MyGroupAcc.active_vacation_data.all
end

#app/views/my_group_acc/my_group.html.erb
%table.table.table-bordered.trace-table
    %thead
      %tr.trace-table
        %th.ts.jp{:style => 'border: solid black;'} Person ID
        %th.ts.jp{:style => 'border: solid black;'} Total Vacation Days

        %tr.trace-table
     - @peoples_vacation_information.each do |person|
        %tr.trace-table
          %td.trace-table{:style => 'border: solid black;'}= "person #{person.person_id} has #{person.total_v_days} vacation days"
<% end %>
```

The problem is you're your `@p` variable as a string (which `rob` fixed).

Apart from the syntax problem, it's badly constructed for two reasons - first, you're splitting up a perfectly good *collection* (which you could just pass to your view), and secondly, you're trying to construct another piece of data only to split it up.

You'll be best setting an `@instance_variable` in your controller, you can then loop through in your view.

---

You'll also be best using [`scopes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) in your `MyGroupAcc` model (which can be chained, don't worry):

```
#app/models/my_group_acc.rb
class MyGroupAcc < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :entry

    scope :all_people,           -> { where(person_id: User.pluck(:person_id)) }
    scope :active_people,        -> { where is_active: "Y" }
    scope :active_vacation_data, -> { active_people.select(:person_id, :accum_accrued, :taken) }

    def total_v_hours
       accum_accrued.to_d - taken.to_d
    end

    def total_v_days
       total_v_hours / 8
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion both answers worked well for me! @RichPeck